# What is right way to get IP address in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I have two standalone exe's Parent.exe and Child.exe.

Parent.exe opens Child.exe and some operation are performed in child.exe by user then
child.exe sends back some processed data to Parent.exe. Both exe's stays on same machine

The communication between Child.Exe and Parent.Exe is being done through TCP IP (Socket Programming). For this we need to calculate the Local IP Address, we used to calculate it in the following way :-

```
       string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();

       IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
       IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
       string FinalIpAddrs = addr[0]
```

Everything worked fine at XP but with Windows 7 we are facing problem. The below line return Mac Address what is the right way to do it, so that it works on XP and Win7 both?

```
       string FinalIpAddrs = addr[0]
```

Comment: If both exe's are on the same machine, why not use 127.0.0.1, localhost, or named pipes?

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that app is designed in such a way that client.exe can be placed on another machines as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, those wh program and do not know.

- You do NOT need to know an IP Address, use 127.0.0.1, which is a local loopback address. SImple like that - it is there for exactly that reason.
- Consider being efficient. If that is all same machine, the usage of TCP is bad. Use named pipes, which are a windows integrated commmunciation mechanism that CAN work cross machine, but on the same machine it uses shared memory which is a LOT more efficient than TCP.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that app is designed in such a way that client.exe can be placed on another machines as well

Comment: Well, still - in this case finding the IP addressmay get you the wrong one - compuers tehse days have MULTIPLE, especially if you take IPv6 into account where a computer normally has 2-3 (link, local, public).

Comment: Right I want to take out ip from IPv4, so what is the proper way?

Comment: take out the IPv4 that is not local and filter therest and hope that you only have simplistic setups. But you have to enter the IP manually on other computers anyway, so teh whole problem you demonstrate is home made, as you can not find the correct ip to use from another computer.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use [`IPAddress.Loopback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.loopback.aspx) (or `IPv6Loopback`)?

The loopback addresses are designed for communications entirely on the same host.

---

I'm also guessing that where you say:

> The below line return Mac Address

What you actually mean is that it's returning an IPv6 address. There's no way that that code should be able to return a MAC Address.

Comment: Right by MAC like address I mean to say that it return IPV6 addresses

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific requirement NOT to use 127.0.0.1? If no, then I'd just use it without any calculations.